# Error when using Apache Spark decision tree classifier for multiclass classification

Tags: java, apache-spark, classification, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree

I am trying to classify the user activity based on the sensor data taken from mobile device. Dataset contains user id, sensor data and the activity. Activity is given as an integer and there are 12 classes of activity. Given below is the code I used for my activity recognition classification problem. I am using Apache Spark decision tree for multi class classification problem.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import scala.Tuple2;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeModel;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils;

public class DecisionTreeClass {
    public  static void main(String args[]){
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DecisionTreeClass").setMaster("local[2]");
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);


        // Load and parse the data file.
        String datapath = "/home/thamali/Desktop/Project/csv/libsvm/trainlib.txt";
        JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(jsc.sc(), datapath).toJavaRDD();
        // Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
        JavaRDD<LabeledPoint>[] splits = data.randomSplit(new double[]{0.7, 0.3});
        JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> trainingData = splits[0];
        JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> testData = splits[1];

        // Set parameters.
        //  Empty categoricalFeaturesInfo indicates all features are continuous.
        Integer numClasses = 12;
        Map<Integer, Integer> categoricalFeaturesInfo = new HashMap();
        String impurity = "gini";
        Integer maxDepth = 5;
        Integer maxBins = 32;

        // Train a DecisionTree model for classification.
        final DecisionTreeModel model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses,
                categoricalFeaturesInfo, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins);

        // Evaluate model on test instances and compute test error
        JavaPairRDD<Double, Double> predictionAndLabel =
                testData.mapToPair(new PairFunction<LabeledPoint, Double, Double>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<Double, Double> call(LabeledPoint p) {
                        return new Tuple2(model.predict(p.features()), p.label());
                    }
                });
        Double testErr =
                1.0 * predictionAndLabel.filter(new Function<Tuple2<Double, Double>, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(Tuple2<Double, Double> pl) {
                        return !pl._1().equals(pl._2());
                    }
                }).count() / testData.count();

        System.out.println("Test Error: " + testErr);
        System.out.println("Learned classification tree model:\n" + model.toDebugString());

        // Save and load model
        model.save(jsc.sc(), "target/tmp/myDecisionTreeClassificationModel");
        DecisionTreeModel sameModel = DecisionTreeModel
                .load(jsc.sc(), "target/tmp/myDecisionTreeClassificationModel");
// $example off$
    }

}
```

When using the above code I got following exception. Can someone please help me to solve the problem.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GiniAggregator given label 17.0 but requires label < numClasses (= 12).
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impurity.GiniAggregator.update(Gini.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.DTStatsAggregator.update(DTStatsAggregator.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$.orderedBinSeqOp(RandomForest.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$.org$apache$spark$ml$tree$impl$RandomForest$$nodeBinSeqOp$1(RandomForest.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ml$tree$impl$RandomForest$$binSeqOp$1$1.apply(RandomForest.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ml$tree$impl$RandomForest$$binSeqOp$1$1.apply(RandomForest.scala:439)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$.org$apache$spark$ml$tree$impl$RandomForest$$binSeqOp$1(RandomForest.scala:439)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(RandomForest.scala:532)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(RandomForest.scala:532)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$$anonfun$9.apply(RandomForest.scala:532)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.RandomForest$$anonfun$9.apply(RandomForest.scala:521)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Check your data - `given label 17.0 but requires label < numClasses (= 12)` so somewhere in your dataset you've got label 17

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
Integer numClasses = 17;
```